# How to combine these two PostgreSQL statements into one for Rails 3 application?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I have two PostgreSQL statements that I would like to combine in my RoR application.

The first SQL statement returns a link where the link contains two specific tag_ids.

```
SELECT link_id, count(*) as counter
  FROM "totals"
 WHERE "totals"."tag_id" IN (6, 8)
   AND (score > 0)
 GROUP BY link_id
HAVING count(*)=2
```

RoR ActiveRecord version:

```
 links = Total.find_all_by_tag_id(@tag_list, :conditions => ["score > 0"], :select => "link_id, count(*) as counter", :having => "count(*)=#{@tag_list.count}", :group => "link_id").collect(&:link_id).uniq.sort.reverse
```

The second SQL statement returns the links that have the highest score of a specific tag_id.

```
SELECT s1.link_id
  FROM totals AS s1
     , (SELECT link_id
              , MAX(score) AS maxscore
          FROM totals
         GROUP BY link_id) as s2
 WHERE s2.link_id = s1.link_id
   and s1.score = s2.maxscore
   AND s1.score > 0 AND s1.tag_id = 6
```

The table is constructed like this:

```
totals:
  link_id : integer
  tag_id : integer
  score : integer

=============================
| link_id  | tag_id | score |
=============================
|    1     |    6   |   5   |
|    1     |    8   |   2   |
|    1     |    3   |   1   |
|    2     |    6   |   6   |
|    2     |    4   |   2   |
|    2     |    8   |   6   |
|    3     |    6   |   5   |
|    3     |    2   |   4   |
|    4     |    2   |   4   |
|    4     |    6   |   1   |
|    4     |    8   |   2   |
=============================
```

The first SQL statement would return the `link_ids` `1, 2 and 4` and the second SQL statement would return `link_ids` `1, 2 and 3`.

How can I combine the two SQL statements into one, so that I get the highest score of a specific tag containing multiple selected tags?

The combined statement should return the `link_ids` `1 and 2`.

The DDL and INSERT commands can be found here: http://sqlize.com/480glD5Is4

It would be great if this could be written in RoR ActiveRecord style or in a much more optimal SQL statement.

Many thanks.

Comment: Would you be able to share the DDL (create table(s) statements) so that we can try them out at http://sqlize.com/ ?

Comment: What should the outcome of the example look like? It is still unclear to me, was you want to get exactly.

Comment: The expected outcome after the two statements are combined should return the value of `link_id 1`.

Comment: Hi Michael, here is the sqlize link [sqlize.com/zO10AM8Tx6](http://sqlize.com/zO10AM8Tx6).

Answer (score 1):

> The first SQL statement returns a link where the link contains two
>   specific tag_ids.

That works if and only if there's either a primary key constraint or a unique constraint on {link_id, tag_id}. I added that constraint (makes sense) and I'll include the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for others. (You should have done that. You edit your question and paste this stuff in if you want to.)

```
create table totals (
  link_id  integer not null,
  tag_id integer not null,
  score integer not null,
  primary key (link_id, tag_id)
);

insert into totals values
(1, 6, 5   ),
(1, 8, 2   ),
(1, 3, 1   ),
(2, 6, 6   ),
(2, 4, 2   ),
(3, 6, 1   ),
(3, 2, 4   ),
(3, 8, 3   ),
(4, 2, 4   ),
(4, 6, 1   ),
(4, 8, 2   );
```

Rephrasing the question, based on comments, you're looking for link id numbers that have

- both tag id numbers 6 and 8, and
- whose score for tag id 6 is higher than their score for tag id 8

To start with, it's easy to see that these two queries will give you the scores for

- all the rows that have tag_id = 6, and
- all the rows that have tag_id = 8

  ```
  select *
  from totals
  where tag_id = 6

  select *
  from totals
  where tag_id = 8
  ```

That's simple enough.

We can join the two queries easily with a common table expression.

```
with score_for_8 as (
  select *
  from totals
  where tag_id = 8
) 
select totals.* 
from totals 
inner join score_for_8
        on score_for_8.link_id = totals.link_id and
           totals.score > score_for_8.score 
where totals.tag_id = 6;
```

Since this doesn't require grouping, ordering, or limiting the result set, it will correctly report ties.

I'm pretty sure this still isn't quite what you're looking for, but I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response Catcall. I tried out the SQL and although it is returning links with `tag_ids 6 and 8` it is not returning links that only have `tag_id 6` as being the highest score out of the links other tag scores.

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clearer but it is acceptable to have more than one `link_id` returned.

Comment: @davicta: You want link id numbers that have both tag id numbers 6 and 8, and whose score for tag id 6 is higher than their score for tag id 8?

Comment: Yes and for any other tag_id that the link may have a score for.

Comment: @davicta: I don't understand. You said earlier you wanted the query to return "the value of link id 1". Should it a) return one row for link id 1, b) should it return all three rows for link id 1, or c) return only those rows for link id 1 that have lower scores than tag id 6? ( I know there aren't yet any rows that have a higher score for a different tag id, but there could be a `ROW(1, 4, 20)`.)

Comment: Based on the initial data set the combined SQL statement will return link_id 1 because a) the link has a tag_id 6 which is the max score out of the other tag_ids the link has and b) has both tag_ids 6 and 8. If link_id 2 had another tag_id 8 with a score of 6 and under it would also be returned along with link_id 1. Really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: @davicta: You should edit your question, add more representative data, and include the DDL and INSERT statements.